# Using set()/setp() to set unknown properties in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working in matplotlib with a figure that can be modified by the user. Due to the way the app is designed, when the user wants to change a property of the figure, such as the `xlim` for example, the input is received in a dictionary such as `{'xlim': value}`.

Since I can't know in advance which properties the user will want to change, I've been trying to use `set()` to change the properties; however, when I process the dictionary like this:

```
for key, value in changes.iteritems():
            if self.seen[key][1] == 1:  # Key is seen
                self.obj.set(key=value)
```

I get the error: `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_key'`

Is there any other way to set properties in matplotlib where I don't need to know in advance *which* specific property is going to be changed? I really can't think of a way to work around this without using `set()`/`setp()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [cphlewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1168043/cphlewis) already pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30340038/4177384), the problem lies in how you pass the key/value pair to `set`.

But your problem is not related to matplotlib, it is a general python problem: A function defined like `set` in matplotlib receives the keyword arguments in `**kwargs` as a dictionary. The keys are *always* strings! Thus if you have a function `func`:

```
def func(**kwargs):
    pass
```

and call it with:

```
func(foo='bar')
```

then `kwargs` will be a dictionary: `{'foo':'bar'}`. Thus if you call:

```
key = 'foo'
value = 1
ax.set(key=value)
```

then `ax.set` will receive this dictionary: `{'key':1}` (and **not** `{'foo':1}`!). And since `key` is not a property of `axes`, this results in an error.

So you could do it like this:

```
kwargs_for_set = dict()
for key, value in changes.iteritems():
    if self.seen[key][1] == 1:  # Key is seen
        kwargs_for_set[key] = value
self.obj.set(**kwargs_for_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

More of the stack trace for that error:

```
    826             funcName = "set_%s" % k
--> 827             func = getattr(self, funcName)
    828             ret.extend([func(v)])
    829         return ret

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_key'
```

Look how `key` is being used -- its name ('key'), not its value ('xlim' or whatever).

I'd add elements to my kwarg dictionary as the user modified the plot. Where, in script, I'd do

```
ax.set(title='foo')
```

> ```
> Out[59]: [<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x10b936110>]
> ```

instead I'd accumulate and use kwargs like so:

```
kwargs = {'title':'foo'}

ax.set(**kwargs)
```

> ```
> Out[61]: [<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x10b936110>]
> ```

same output, reassuring.